# All my weights for gradient descent become 0 on feature expansion

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I have 2 features which I expand to contain all possible combinations of the two features under order 6. When I do `MATLAB's` `fminunc`, it returns a weight vector where all elements are 0.

The dataset is [here](https://pastebin.com/M3zhZWhJ)

```
clear all;
clc;
data = load("P2-data1.txt");
m = length(data);
para = 0; % regularization parameter

%% Augment Feature
y = data(:,3);
new_data = newfeature(data(:,1), data(:,2), 3);

[~, n] = size(new_data);
betas1 = zeros(n,1); % initial weights
options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400);
[beta_new, cost] = fminunc(@(t)(regucostfunction(t, new_data, y, para)), betas1, options);

fprintf('Cost at theta found by fminunc: %f\n', cost);
fprintf('theta: \n');
fprintf(' %f \n', beta_new); % get all 0 here
% Compute accuracy on our training set
p_new = predict(beta_new, new_data);
fprintf('Train Accuracy after feature augmentation: %f\n', mean(double(p_new == y)) * 100);
fprintf('\n');

%% the functions are defined below
function g = sigmoid(z) % running properly

    g = zeros(size(z));
    g=ones(size(z))./(ones(size(z))+exp(-z));
end

function [J,grad] = regucostfunction(theta,x,y,para) % CalculateCost(x1,betas1,y);
    m = length(y); % number of training examples
    J = 0;
    grad = zeros(size(theta));
    hyp = sigmoid(x*theta);
    err = (hyp - y)';
    grad = (1/m)*(err)*x;
    sum = 0;
    for k = 2:length(theta)
        sum = sum+theta(k)^2;
    end
    J = (1/m)*((-y' * log(hyp) - (1 - y)' * log(1 - hyp)) + para*(sum) );
end

function p = predict(theta, X)
    m = size(X, 1); % Number of training examples
    p = zeros(m, 1);
    index = find(sigmoid(theta'*X') >= 0.5);
    p(index,1) = 1;
end

function out = newfeature(X1, X2, degree)
    out = ones(size(X1(:,1)));
    for i = 1:degree
        for j = 0:i
            out(:, end+1) = (X1.^(i-j)).*(X2.^j);
        end
    end

end
```

`data` contains 2 columns of rows followed by a third column of 0/1 values.

The functions used are: `newfeature` returns the expanded features and `regucostfunction` computes the cost. When I did the same approach with the default features, it worked and I think the problem here has to do with some coding issue.

Comment: can you post your functions as well, otherwise we can't reproduce the behaviour you describe

Comment: You need to define the problem. If its non-covex, gradient descend will not work. Or maybe you did something wrong with the code. But we need the [mcve] for that!

Comment: @DavidS I have edited to reproduce the error

Comment: @user3656142 I'm not sure that there is a coding issue, the code as posted currently is working, also when changing `new_data = newfeature(data(:,1), data(:,2), X);` X=2,3,4 the weights are not all 0 (but for X=5,6,7..) they are. I think that after doing the `newfeature()` the problem is no longer convex and thus stays at the starting point which is 0

Comment: Yes I think when I have too many features, the weights become ) for some mathematical features. With limited features, the weights are non-zero. @DavidS thanks for checking out the code.